# Why does Nutch think it has already parsed all segments when it hasn't?

Tags: parsing, nutch

I'm using Nutch 1.6 to crawl some forums and index them with Solr 1.6.2. I ran a test query on Solr and was surprised that there were only a few results. I was worried that there was a problem either with Nutch's parsing of the pages or with Solr's indexing. After snooping around I found out that Nutch hasn't parsed a lot of the pages it has retrieved:

```
bin/nutch readseg -list -dir crawl-mothering2/segments/

NAME        GENERATED   FETCHED   PARSED
20130228001531  23      27        9
20130228003940  1430    1434      661
20130228001829  202     206       105
20130228061337  1068    1090      475
20130228091009  1       2         0
20130228085956  34      34        25
20130228090348  44      45        34
20130228090851  7       7         6
20130228080438  364     374       192
20130228030933  1774    1795      903
20130228084205  168     169       63
```

But when I try to parse the segments, I get this:

```
bin/nutch parse crawl-mothering2/segments/*
ParseSegment: starting at 2013-03-21 00:20:43
ParseSegment: segment: crawl-mothering2/segments/20130228001531
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Segment already parsed!
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(ParseOutputFormat.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment.parse(ParseSegment.java:209)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment.run(ParseSegment.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment.main(ParseSegment.java:216)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-parse, go into the crawl/segments/ and

```
rm -rf parse_text parse_data crawl_parse
```

then you can run

```
bin/nutch parse crawldir/segments/<segmentnumber>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nutch cannot reparse segments. To overcome this, you would need to delete few folders. Please check the mailing list discussion http://www.mail-archive.com/user@nutch.apache.org/msg09017.html.

You will get faster response at http://nutch.apache.org/mailing_lists.html